# Firebase query returning empty snapshot in Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

My firebase query to get the recent matches is empty and I am not sure why. I attached a photo of my query and of my "Match" collection. When I remove the whereField for "date" and orderBy "date", it fetches the matches. But with that part of the query added, it is returning an empty snapshot.

My Fuser.currentUser is xFLLcqkXOjc2uNMWcLJyrHeryRC2, so there should be a match returned.

**Working:**

```swift
FirebaseReference(.Match)
  .whereField("memberIds", arrayContains: FUser.currentId())
  .getDocuments
```

**Not working:**

```swift
FirebaseReference(.Match)
  .whereField("memberIds", arrayContains: FUser.currentId())
  .whereField(kDATE, isGreaterThan: lastMonth)
  .order(by: "date", descending: true)
  .getDocuments
```

&& this returns an empty snapshot too:

```swift
FirebaseReference(.Match)
  .whereField("memberIds", arrayContains: FUser.currentId()))
  .order(by: "date", descending: true)
  .getDocuments
```

[image]
[image]

I tried to change the query, but no luck once the "date" is either added to the query by a whereField or an orderBy field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every query you run on Firestore needs to have an index that matches its conditions and ordering statement. For that first query the index is auto-generated, but the other queries look like they'll all need a composite index that you need to explicitly tell Firestore to generate.

The easiest way to generate the required index is to:

1. Catch any error that your code may raise and log them.
2. Find the error message in the log output.
3. Find the URL link in there and click it.
4. This takes you to the Firestore console, on a page to generate the index, with all details for the index already filled out. So all you have to do it.
5. Click the button to start generating the index.

Wait for the index to be generated (this may take some time), and then try again.

Also see the Firestore documentation on its [index types](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/index-overview).